# Resources on getting horus/ciclop scanners to work?

Tags: software, scanning, open-source

I have a Ciclop (HE3D version) scanner ready to try to use, but it seems the Horus software is hopelessly bitrotted. It has breakage from API-level changes at least in the Python bindings for OpenGL, OpenCV, matplotlib, and wxPython, and possibly also incompatibility with the V4L2 camera drivers for Linux versions later than whatever the authors were using at the time. After attempting to fix those as best I can, I'm still getting no output from the camera. (Note: The camera works fine with other apps and OpenCV test program, so it's not a camera problem.)

Is anyone using the Horus software successfully? Are there forks or alternate software that are usable, or exact details on what historical operating system and Python ecosystem version is needed to make it work?

Comment: How is a tool for 3D scanning not also a tool for 3D printing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work but BQ commercializes a Ciclops scanner and have some downloads in their webpage (https://www.bq.com/en/support/ciclop/support-sheet).

There are different Horus and driver versions, maybe some will work for you(?).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't appear to. The release versions of Horus there (0.1.x) are older than the version I have from git, and even that is bitrotted with respect to modern versions of all the python modules it uses. Making this work is probably going to require actively fixing it or containerizing it (or just running on a dedicated box) with horribly outdated OS/packages... :(